# Controls in VSCode Custom Views

Tags: visual-studio-code

Now that VSCode has Custom Views, how can I implement one containing a simple textbox or anything but Tree?
The only example that I found is `Azure Tools` and it only registers tree items...

What I am after is something more like a Search panel. Is it possible to do it with VSCode Custom Views?

Comment: Looking for the same answer as well

Comment: @Jaime, are you talking about https://github.com/bradygaster/azure-tools-vscode, also what exactly do you want can you explain?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I want to put something different than a treeview (which currently I tried already), but maybe some textboxes and button. Something similar to the Search view.

Comment: @Jaime Same for me: I would like to add textboxes and buttons.

Answer (score 0):

As of VS Code 1.29, you cannot add a search/input box to a tree view. This is tracked by [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/50062)

You can add custom buttons to the top of a tree view using the `menus -> view/title` contribution point:

```
"menus": {
  "view/title": [
    {
      "command": "myCommand",
      "group": "navigation",
      "when": "view == myTreeView.id"
    }
  ]
```

LiveShare for example adds a `join` and `start` button:

[image]

You can also treat tree view items themselves as ad-hoc buttons. The Azure CosmosDB extension does this:

[image]

Please [open a feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new?template=feature_request.md) if you are looking for more extensive customization